# Почему не получается установить neat

Tags: python, pip, установка, neat

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку *neat*, прописывая в cmd следующую  команду: `pip install neat`. Но у меня выдается непонятная ошибка, причем на двух устройствах сразу, которую я не знаю, как решить. Помогите, пожалуйста, как разрешить проблему.

Вот ошибка:

```
Collecting neat
  Using cached neat-0.4.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in neat setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Вот скриншот: https://imgur.com/eLxL6ll

Comment: https://discuss.python.org/t/getting-requirements-to-build-wheel-did-not-run-successfully-exit-code-1/30365

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй написать pip install neat-python, мне помогло